How to save the plot from SHAP (SHapley Additive exPlanations) library? (posx and posy should be finite values)
I'm using SHAP to explain the predictions of an XGBoost model trained for binary classification. Specifically, I'm trying to generate and save a SHAP's force plot to visualize the contribution of each feature to the model's output. I'm encountering an issue where the saved image is blank (completely white) instead of displaying the expected plot. I'm trying to save a force plot using SHAP , but I keep encountering the following error  repeatedly:
posx and posy should be finite values
posx and posy should be finite values
...

Here is my code for SHAP to visualize the impact of features on my model's predictions and I would like to save the force plot as an image file (e.g., PNG). However, I'm encountering an issue with the following code.
import shap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Get indexes for specific classes
class_1_indexes = np.where(y_test == 1)[0]
class_0_indexes = np.where(y_test == 0)[0]

# Create SHAP explainer and values
shap_explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = shap_explainer.shap_values(X_test)

# Create a force plot
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 3))  # Set the figure size

shap.force_plot(
    shap_explainer.expected_value,
    shap_values[class_1_indexes[5]],
    X_test[class_1_indexes[5]],  # Assuming X_test is a DataFrame
    feature_names=feature_names,
    link='logit',
    matplotlib=True,
    text_rotation=7,
    show=False  # Prevent the plot from showing immediately
)

# Save the figure
plt.savefig('shap_force_plot.png', bbox_inches='tight')

# Optionally, show the plot if needed
plt.show()


When I try to save the SHAP force plot, I was getting a blank white image instead of the expected plot.  I'm getting the error posx and posy should be finite values when attempting to save the plot.
Here is the output of my code.

How can I properly save a SHAP force plot as an image (PNG)? increase the graph size and font size?
